# NUCLEO-H743ZI2 lwIP TCP Connection

Tags: stm32, tcpclient, ethernet, lwip

How can I establish a TCP Connection with an NUCLEO-H743ZI2 ?

I managed to establish a simple TCP Connection with a NUCLEO-F429ZI and my PC using the lwIP stack (without FreeRTOS). The NUCLEO-F429ZI was the client and connected to a server, which was running on my pc using hercules. This worked without any problems. Now I tried to use a NUCLEO-H743ZI2 instead, because I needed more RAM for my application. I implemented basecally the same application but the tcp connection is never established. After calling `tcp_connect(...)` the callback is never called.

I tried multiple different firmwares and configurations but nothing worked for me.

I followed this guide: 
https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-Ethernet-not-working-on-STM32H7x3

And used the linkerscript and the `MPU_Config()` function from the example project but it still
doesn't work.

I also tried to use this answer:
[STM32H7 LAN8742 LwIP only works fine after power-up, not after reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260931/stm32h7-lan8742-lwip-only-works-fine-after-power-up-not-after-reset)
I looked through the github repository and tried to match my code but this didn't work either.

Does anybody have an idea what I might be doing wrong ?

If you need any code just ask and I'll provide it as fast as possible.

Thank you for taking the time to read (and hopefully answer) this :)

Comment: Ok i found this: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AnsIJeSQM/how-to-get-ethernet-working-again-after-upgrading-to-firmware-fwh7v140-

and someone suggested to put `SCB_CleanDCache_by_Addr(q->payload, q->len);` into `low_level_output` and that worked for me. Still, now I'm kinda wondering how reliable this will be...

Comment: Well this fixed the problem of establishing the connection, however I can't send any data via tcp like on the NUCLEO-F429ZI ...

Comment: Ok I fixed both bugs by using `SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache();` as shown here:https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWuy/why-stm32cubefwh7v120-ethernet-sample-code-not-run-in-nucleoh743zi-board

I actually tried this before and it didn't work (probably because of wrong MPU config). I will post a complete working solution once its finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so what worked for me was to ensure 3 thinks:

1. Use the right Linkerscript
2. Configure the MPU
3. Add SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache(); in low_level_output(...)

**Linkerscript:**

It is important that the Data for Ethernet is stored in the right locations.
Therefore you can simply use the linkerscript from the example:
https://github.com/bkht/Nucleo-H743ZI_LAN8742_LwIP_NO-SYS/blob/master/TrueSTUDIO/Nucleo-H743ZI_Jack_012_tcp_LAN8742_gh/STM32H743ZI_FLASH.ld

STM32H743ZI_FLASH.ld:

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**

**  File        : stm32_flash.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32H743ZI Device with
**                2048KByte FLASH, 1056KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Environment : Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R)
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Atollic AB.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. This file may only be built (assembled or compiled and linked)
**  using the Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) product. The use of this file together
**  with other tools than Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) is not permitted.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x24080000;    /* end of RAM was 0x20020000 */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x2000;      /* required amount of heap  was 0x1000 */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x4000; /* required amount of stack  was 0x1000 */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
DTCMRAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
RAM_D1 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 512K
RAM_D2 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
RAM_D3 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
ITCMRAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  /* } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH */
  } >RAM_D1 AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  /* } >DTCMRAM */
  } >RAM_D1


  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >DTCMRAM




  .lwip_sec (NOLOAD) : {
    . = ABSOLUTE(0x30040000);
    *(.RxDecripSection) 

    . = ABSOLUTE(0x30040060);
    *(.TxDecripSection)

    . = ABSOLUTE(0x30040200);
    *(.RxArraySection) 
  } >RAM_D2 AT> FLASH


  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

**MPU Config:**

Also you should use the same MPU_Config() as the example project which is defined here:https://github.com/bkht/Nucleo-H743ZI_LAN8742_LwIP_NO-SYS/blob/master/Src/main.c

```
void MPU_Config(void)
{
  MPU_Region_InitTypeDef MPU_InitStruct = {0};

  /* Disables the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Disable();
  /**Initializes and configures the Region and the memory to be protected
  */
  MPU_InitStruct.Enable = MPU_REGION_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.Number = MPU_REGION_NUMBER0;
  MPU_InitStruct.BaseAddress = 0x30040000;
  MPU_InitStruct.Size = MPU_REGION_SIZE_256B;
  MPU_InitStruct.SubRegionDisable = 0x0;
  MPU_InitStruct.TypeExtField = MPU_TEX_LEVEL0;
  MPU_InitStruct.AccessPermission = MPU_REGION_FULL_ACCESS;
  MPU_InitStruct.DisableExec = MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_SHAREABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsCacheable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_CACHEABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsBufferable = MPU_ACCESS_BUFFERABLE;

  HAL_MPU_ConfigRegion(&MPU_InitStruct);
  /**Initializes and configures the Region and the memory to be protected
  */
  MPU_InitStruct.Enable = MPU_REGION_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.Number = MPU_REGION_NUMBER1;
  MPU_InitStruct.BaseAddress = 0x30044000;
  MPU_InitStruct.Size = MPU_REGION_SIZE_16KB;
  MPU_InitStruct.SubRegionDisable = 0x0;
  MPU_InitStruct.TypeExtField = MPU_TEX_LEVEL0;
  MPU_InitStruct.AccessPermission = MPU_REGION_NO_ACCESS;
  MPU_InitStruct.DisableExec = MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_SHAREABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsCacheable = MPU_ACCESS_CACHEABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsBufferable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_BUFFERABLE;

  HAL_MPU_ConfigRegion(&MPU_InitStruct);
  /* Enables the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Enable(MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT);

}
```

Call it at the start of main:

```
int main(void)
{

  MPU_Config();
  ...

}
```

**Add SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache(); in low_level_output(...):**

The function `static err_t low_level_output(struct netif *netif, struct pbuf *p)` is located in **ethernetif.c**. You have to add the function `SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache();` near the end like this:

```
static err_t low_level_output(struct netif *netif, struct pbuf *p)
{
  ...  

  SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache(); //<-- Add this line if it is missing
  HAL_ETH_Transmit(&heth, &TxConfig, ETH_DMA_TRANSMIT_TIMEOUT);

  return errval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue.
I'm using STM32H743. I can't ping. Ping from PC does timeout

added SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache(); to low_level_output() function before HAL_ETH_Transmit()

I'm using IAR, so we have an icf. file.
CubeMx generates the following

```
#if defined ( __ICCARM__ ) /*!< IAR Compiler */

#pragma location=0x30000000
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Rx DMA Descriptors */
#pragma location=0x30000100
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Tx DMA Descriptors */
```

I checked DMATxDscrTab address in the watch window when my program is running, and it's correct 0x30000100 and DMARxDscrTab 0x30000000.

I followed the steps in
https://controllerstech.com/stm32-ethernet-1-connection/

my DCache and ICache are enabled at the start of main() such as

```
  /* MPU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
  MPU_Config();

  /* Enable I-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  SCB_EnableICache();

  /* Enable D-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  SCB_EnableDCache();
```

my MPU is set as following

```
void MPU_Config(void)
{
  MPU_Region_InitTypeDef MPU_InitStruct = {0};

  /* Disables the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Disable();

  /** Initializes and configures the Region and the memory to be protected
  */
  MPU_InitStruct.Enable = MPU_REGION_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.Number = MPU_REGION_NUMBER0;
  MPU_InitStruct.BaseAddress = 0x30000000;
  MPU_InitStruct.Size = MPU_REGION_SIZE_32KB;
  MPU_InitStruct.SubRegionDisable = 0x0;
  MPU_InitStruct.TypeExtField = MPU_TEX_LEVEL1;
  MPU_InitStruct.AccessPermission = MPU_REGION_FULL_ACCESS;
  MPU_InitStruct.DisableExec = MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_DISABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_SHAREABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsCacheable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_CACHEABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsBufferable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_BUFFERABLE;

  HAL_MPU_ConfigRegion(&MPU_InitStruct);
  /* Enables the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Enable(MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT);

}
```

what's the problem here.
I can read the PHY registers.
The link is up in LWIP but server (PC) cannot ping.
thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35249121)